# Does GCDAsyncSocket can readData automaticlly

Tags: ios, sockets

I use iPad connect to a server which runs a Python script. Server will send message to iPad continuously. But the interval is not a constant.
When i call this method:

```
[newSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

I can get the message i want from server:

```
-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
```

But my question is do i have to call `readDataWithTimeout` frequently, like in a `NSTimer`. Or any way if the server post a message my client/iPad can get it automaticly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to call it once, but when `socket:didReadData:withTag:` is called, you will need to call `readDataWithTimeout:` again if you are expecting more data.

an example i have lying around(in swift):

```
func socket(sock: GCDAsyncSocket!, didAcceptNewSocket newSocket: GCDAsyncSocket?) {
    println("new connection recieved \(newSocket?.hash) old: \(sock?.hash)");

    socketRead = newSocket;

    self.socketRead?.readDataToData(self.dataDelimiter, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0) //start reading
}

func socket(sock: GCDAsyncSocket!, didReadData data: NSData!, withTag tag: Int) {

    var mutableData:NSMutableData = NSMutableData();
    mutableData.appendBytes(data.bytes, length: data.length-dataDelimiter.length) //remove delimiter
    var error:NSError?
    var jsonDic:NSDictionary? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(mutableData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &error) as? NSDictionary;

    //println("did read data: \(NSString(data: mutableData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")

    if(sock == socketRead){

        if(jsonDic != nil){
            serverSentMessage(jsonDic!)
        }

        self.socketRead?.readDataToData(self.dataDelimiter, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0) //continue reading data
    }
    //have other sockets that only need to read once ever so dont do anything for those
}
```